# Producing PDFs in landscape orientation with ReportLab

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I am working on a Python script that produces a PDF report using ReportLab. I need to produce the pages in landscape orientation and I have already looked through the ReportLab manual but I can't find a way of doing this. Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make sure you've imported

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, landscape
```

And then:

```
canvas.setPageSize(landscape(letter))
```

Or more generally,

```
canvas.setPageSize(width, height)
```

and you can set it to be any size you like. Remember reportlab uses points, where 1 point is 1/72 of an inch. You can also import:

```
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
```

Which lets you do things like:

```
canvas.setPageSize(11*inch, 8.5*inch)
```

EDIT: Added all the built in page sizes inspired by yentsun.

Diving into the `reportlab.lib.pagesizes` source code, we find in all:

```
A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6
B0,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6
LETTER, LEGAL, ELEVENSEVENTEEN
```

The comments claims that the lowercase `letter` has been deprecated since 2001, but is still available. Additionally, two functions are avaialable, `portrait` and `landscape` that each take in a tuple pagesize, and portrait returns the tuple with the smaller dimension first, and landscape returns the tuple with the larger dimension first.

Comment: And if we're talking about A4 landscape, then swap `letter` to `A4`

Answer (score 1):

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, landscape
```

And then define the page size and orientation.

```
p = canvas.Canvas(response, pagesize=(landscape(letter)))
```